# Metaprogramming template recursion doesn't recurse (edited important)

Tags: c++, recursion, metaprogramming

I try to invoke function void set (...) recursively using metaprogramming.
The problem is that it seems to invokes only once.

```
template <int N>
struct GEN
{
    enum {value = GEN<N-1>::value};
    template <typename T> 
    static inline void set(T& tup, int l_item) 
    { 
        cout<<"item value: "<<l_item<<", N-1: "<< N-1 << ",  value: "<<value <<endl;
        typedef typename boost::tuples::element<N-1, T>::type _el_type;
        get<N-1>(tup) = atomic_item<N-1, _el_type>(l_item); 
    };
};

template<>
struct GEN<0>
{
    enum {value = 0};
    template <typename T> 
    static inline void set(T& tup, int l_item) 
    {
        typedef typename boost::tuples::element<0, T>::type _el_type;
        get<0>(tup) = atomic_item<0, _el_type>(l_item); 
    };
};

main(){
....
/** this is how i try to invoke it */
GEN<3>::set(w,1);
}
```

Output:

> item value: 1, N-1: 2,  value: 0

function has been invoked only once...

**EDIT**

is there  a way to do kind of loop with for_each or anything else to get something simmilar:

```
for_each<range_c<int,0,3> f{operator()(T i)GEN<typename T::value>::set(w,1)}>
```

or something similar to achieve invoke for all of those elements?

Particularly I'd like to have this:

```
GEN<3>::set(w,1);
GEN<2>::set(w,1);
GEN<1>::set(w,1);
```

In loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no recursion. Recursion means calling yourself. The `set` function in your code does *not* do this.

Your `value` declaration *does* recurse (i.e. `GEN<N>::value` is defined in terms of `GEN<N -1>::value`) – but in a pretty uninteresting way, it just propagates the base case value, 0 – and furthermore you don’t seem to be using this value anyway.

/EDIT: Here’s a very simple example to address the point raised by you in the comments, i.e. to achieve the effect of

```
GEN<3>::set(w,1);
GEN<2>::set(w,1);
GEN<1>::set(w,1);
```

That’s actually pretty easy:

```
template <unsigned N>
struct GEN {
    template <typename T>
    static void set(T& w, int value) {
        // Do something, e.g.:
        get<N - 1>(w) = value;
        // Recurse:
        GEN<N - 1>::set(w, value);
    }
};

template <>
struct GEN<0> {
    template <typename T>
    static void set(T&, int) { /* empty */ }
};
```

Now you can call this code via `GEN<3>::set(w, 1)` and it will have the desired semantics.

Comment: is there  a way to do kind of loop with for_each or anything else to get:
for_each<range_c<int,0,3> f{operator()(T i)GEN<typename T::value>::set(w,1)}>
or something simmilar?

Comment: @bua: no idea. I’ve never worked with `range_c`. But I doubt that it works since `for_each` isn’t expanded at compile time (and as far as I see Boost.MPL doesn’t offer an appropriate mechanism for this). But you *can* make your code work, you just need to insert the recursive call at the right point (I can’t help you there, I don’t really understand what your code is doing since I don’t know `atomic_item`.

Comment: @Kondrad Now I'd like to achieve 
GEN<3>::set(w,1);
GEN<2>::set(w,1);
GEN<1>::set(w,1);
in a loop.

Comment: ha :D your comment //do something eg.  can be changed to my two lines and recursion works ! Thanks mate, I was missing GET<N-1>::set(...) all the time :D

Answer (score 1):

The metaprogramming template obviously *did* recurse since your code compiled and ran.

Were you expecting a recursive call of the `set` function? The function you called, `GEN<3>::set` doesn't call the `set` function of any other class, so there is no run-time recursion. There is only compile-time recursion to instantiate the templates. But compile-time recursion doesn't generate output at run time.